# Looking for a generic Oauth library for scala, java or python

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, scala, oauth

I have a few already but wanted to merge them into one public domain oauth code library for twitter, facebook, friendfeed (and let other developers improve the library for their preferred connections).

I'm having a tough time just debugging mashing friendfeed and twitters oauth into one friendly python program running on the Google App Engine.

These are some of the pieces I have so far:
http://oauth.net/code
http://code.google.com/p/oauth-python-twitter/
http://code.google.com/p/friendfeed-api-example/

Comment: I have been pushing towards a lift solution, for the purposes of learning more about this web framework, and scala the language it's based upon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh oh...

[OAuth here she comes](http://technically.us/code/x/oauth-here-she-comes/) ... she's a scala-based-man-eater!

Full disclosure: I just remembered this article mostly because the title was catchy, more than that I fully grok and support the approach. But I try to think I steal`<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>` *appropriate* ideas from the author enough that I think it's worth reading.

Comment: great link, read the article over quickly. Now giving it a careful read through.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a clean code version, written in scala, works in Java too.

<strike>http://github.com/ben-biddington/scala-oauth</strike>

[UPDATE]

Sorry, I renamed the repo:

http://github.com/ben-biddington/Coriander.OAuth

Comment: the page doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 4):

check out [Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost), it's written in Java, has a dead simple interface, and is service provider independent.

Comment: Signpost is okay, but if you need to do anything moderately out of the ordinary (eg. because you have to integrate with an unusual implementation on a server or because you have to work around bugs in your java platform) its use of final and private all over the place makes it very rigid and inflexible.  Just a word of warning.

Comment: Mike, can you open a ticket for this detailing which parts of its API you feel should be more flexible?

Comment: Signpost does exactly what I needed it to do. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

PyPI lists a [few packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=oauth&submit=search) under OAuth, but I'm not sure how well they match your needs.

Also, there's an [oauth on app engine](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/oauth/oauth_on_appengine) subfolder in the gdata library for python that might be of interest.

Comment: Thanks ars I'll check them out, looking for simple/generic. I think the oauth twitter lib I grabbed fits that bill. 
A friend suggested I dig more into reading about web programming and write something from scratch before I try and go too far with using existing libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For Python there's [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth), an OAuth 1.0/a and 2.0 client library.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw a directory under the main scala lib http://www.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb/lift-oauth/index.html

nothing there yet, but maybe its "in the works"